# Filter Pandas DataFrame with ETFs based on the last working day of the month

Tags: pandas, filtering, stock

I have Pandas DataFrame with daily values of Open, Close, Low, High, Volume values of several ETFs. I want to make filter - to filter last working day for every of the ETFs. with values for that day and if it si possible value for Volume to be Sum of the Volume for total month. The idea is to compare MoM ETFs[image]

I tried several scripts without sucess, could you support me?

Google, ChatGPT. I expected to find how to filter properly for desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that the DataFrame is stored in the variable `df` then you get the data of each Stock with the latest date by filtering:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Stock')['Date'].idxmax()]
```

Consider that the type of column 'Date' should be datetime

Comment: Thank you soo much!
Earlier today I wrote symilar code that wokring it is similar to yours.
Now I am struggling how to add Volume as a sum for total month not with the last value for the month. Could you support me for that too.

Comment: Add columns of year and month then group Volume by stock, year and month as follows: 
`df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year`

`df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month`

`df.groupby(['Stock', 'year', 'month']).agg({'Volume': 'sum'})`